# WYSIWYG XML Editor web application

Tags: javascript, xml, editor, wysiwyg, xml-editor

I need to write a web based WYSIWYG XML Editor with limited functionality.
This application can get and edit some data in xml format.
Add or edit some text and set some tag (from example) and save result.
https://in-frame.com:8088/question.xml
The interface maybe like this: http://fontoxml.com/fontoxml-demo/
Any idea or examples?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<document>
<header>
    <title>Main Hero</title>
    <description>screenplay</description>
    <header-1>authors:</header-1>
    <authors>
        <autor>Author One</autor>
        <autor>Author Two</autor>
    </authors>
</header>
<body>
    <act id="1">
        <title>Act 1</title>
        <sequence>
            <title>Sequence 1</title>
            <scene id="1" name="Scene One">
                <title>1. Scene One.</title>
                <persons>
                    <person actorId="1" name="Person 1">Person 1,</person>
                    <person actorId="2" name="Person 2">Person 2,</person>
                    <person actorId="3" name="Person 3">Person 3</person>
                </persons>
                <block>
                    <action>
                        Some action <person actorId="1" name="Person 1">Person 1</person>, some other action. <person actorId="2" name="Person 2">Person 2</person> any else.
                    </action>
                </block>
                <block>
                    <person actorId="1" name="Person 1">Person 1
                        <remark>Remark</remark>
                        <dialog>Where are you from?</dialog>
                    </person>
                    <action>Some action <person actorId="1" name="Person 2">Person 2</person> - <person actorId="3" name="Person 3">Person 3</person> some else.</action>
                </block>
                <block>
                    <person actorId="3" name="Person 3">Person 3
                        <dialog>I am from NY!</dialog>
                    </person>
                    <action>Action one.</action>
                    <action pov="yes" pov_person="1">Action two.</action>
                </block>
            </scene>
            <scene id="2" name="Scene 2">
                <title>2. Scene 2.</title>
                <persons>
                    <person actorId="1" name="Person 1">Person 1,</person>
                    <person actorId="2" name="Person 2">Person 2,</person>
                </persons>
                <block>
                    <action pov="yes" pov_person="From cameraof person 1">РОV from Person 1: some action.</action>
                </block>
            </scene>
        </sequence>
    </act>
</body>
</document>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer might come a little late, but you could try doing that with [Daxe](http://adopt.github.io/daxe/). It lets you build a web user interface for a customized XML editor, with real-time schema-based validation. You can choose to display elements with predefined display types (some of them are WYSIWYG), or create new ones for your language. It can be integrated in a larger platform to handle opening and saving documents.

Disclaimer: I wrote it.